# Problem with single-page for my custom post

Tags: query-posts, slug, single

I'm working on a website with a portfolio section, and I'm almost finished with this section, but I have a problem with the single page which is :

- whenever i click on any portfolio link, the single page opens but not showing any details except the previous and next link and this works correct.
- Also it uses the single.php and I can't change it.

Taking in consideration my main post link is (**our-portfolio**) and the custom post **(slug = portfolio)**.

I tried this step:

- I have created a new single page with name (single-portfolio.php) and put it in the same place where my ( single.php) is but not working.

***UPDATE***

my Custom Post args:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'menu_icon'=> 'dashicons-groups',
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => true),
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'=> false,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes')
);

    register_post_type( 'port', $args );
```

I hope I haven't missed anything.

Comment: Please show your CPT registration arguments.

Comment: `register_post_type( '???', $args );` ?

Comment: register_post_type( 'port', $args );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks sound, so you should have a look at the code in your `single.php` template, as I suspect that there is something wrong in that template to why nothing is displayed. You should set debug to true in wp-config.php. This should help you locate your problem

Secondly, your `single-posttype.php` is wrongly named. Your post type is registered as "port",  and you are using "portfolio". You should name your single page template the same as your registered post type. So you single template should be names `single-port.php`

Just for extra info, here is a small trick to force a template for use by a custom post type

```
function wpse_template_include( $original_template ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['port'] ) && false == $wp->query_vars['port']  ) {
        return get_template_directory() . '/single-port.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_template_include' );
```

Comment: Secondly part works, now i can use single-port.php but as i said before not showing any details except the previous and next link and this works correct.

Comment: Add the code of your single-port.php to your question

Comment: The page now working but i will create custom fields to test that i can display the value in single-port.php.