# Custom post type single display is ommited

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, single

I've created a custom post type: `tutorials` using generatewp.com generator and registered it with `register_post_type()`.

I'm querying the list of tutorials in a custom page template like that:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query('post_type=tutorial'); ?>
<?php if($query->have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while($query->have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
  <?php endwhile(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To target single tutorial template I've created a file `single-tutorial.php`, placed a loop inside it, and fired the tutorial permalink in the browser.

The `single-tutorial.php` file is ommited from Template Hierarchy and goes directly to index.php.

The premalink is for example: `http://example.com/tutorial/tutorial-name/`.

`index.php` content is loaded instead of `single-tutorial.php`

Why is that? Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141863/31545) and [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141093/31545) If this doesn't help, please post your code then for your custom post type

Comment: My pleasure, glad those links were helpful. :-)